# Your branch is behind by 1 commit

Tags: git

I tried to push a few files that were too large so I got an error:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13), completed with 8 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 283e2e5923ebdd63ad935b0d6bbdf8b83a4f5d6d1d3d34b0363778b95001302c
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File scripts/format_datasets.nb.html is 202.30 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:AndrewsLabUCSF/Aadrita-AD-participation-education.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:AndrewsLabUCSF/Aadrita-AD-participation-education.git'
```

I tried going back by two commits using `git reset --soft head~2`.

This is what I'm getting when I'm doing `git status`:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

I want to fix this and commit the changes I've made.

Comment: `reset --soft` does not simply "go back two commits". The large files are _still_ in the index.

Comment: Seems like you have a large file in your repo.  The error says `format_datasets.nb.html is 202.30 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

Answer (score 0):

When you do a [`git reset --soft`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---soft) you should be able to see the changed/added files in your working directory. At this point, if you want to pull the latest changes from the main branch, you should [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_description)/[shelve](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html)/backup the uncommitted local changes. And, if you now run the `git pull` command it should grab the latest changes from the remote.

Now, you can unstash (i.e., `git stash pop`/`git stash apply`)/unshelve the changes that you made locally, and follow the steps mentioned in [Git LFS docs](https://git-lfs.com/) to commit the large files.

Answer (score -2):

so pretty much, the remote branch has an additional commit, and you can either merge that latest commit on top of your branch (normally you'd do this, push a feature branch, and submit a merge back to the main branch), or rebase your commits on top of the latest remote commit and try to just push again

pretty much, `git pull origin main` should work, but if you want to go more granular, you can do `git fetch origin main` then either `git merge origin/main` or `git rebase origin/main`

```
git fetch origin main
git rebase --onto origin/main fromSHA main
```

this is probably what you want to do, it will replay your commits from where they diverged to where your current branch is, on top of origin/main which has an additional commit.. which is why you're behind

---

as a side note, I recommend putting this in your `~/.gitconfig` file

```
[alias]
    lg = log --all --decorate --branches --oneline --graph --color --date=short
```

this will allow you to use `git lg` which will give you a good overview of whats going on